# Strangle, or Strangulate?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

A short piece I'm trying my hand at.

> *"Don't you attempt to **strangle** me!" he screamed as her hands closed around his throat "I'll sue you for grievous bodily harm". The scream had its effect — the hands around his throat wavered, then withdrew. One hand went to cover her own mouth as she burst into laughter —the peals ringing throughout the caravan for the first time in weeks, dissipating the built-up tension — the other hand holding onto a nearby rack, keeping her upright. Amid tears of mirth streaming down her eyes, as she almost bent double from laughing, came her gasping rejoinder: "How do you propose to sue me after you've been **strangled**?"*

Here's my confusion -

Do I use *strangle/strangled*, or *strangulate/strangulated*? How are the two different?

Comment: *Strangulate* is nothing but a longer version of *strangle*; it has the same meaning and etymology. If ease of comprehension is your goal, use the shorter, more familiar word.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's not a *proofreading* question, the OP is asking about word choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Strangulate* is more often (but not exclusively) <sup>[citation needed]</sup> used in a medical context that *strangle* lacks:

> **Strangulate** (v). To restrict flow through a vessel, e.g. with a tourniquet.

Independently, the term *strangle* is [about 50-100 times more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strangle%2Cstrangulate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800).

I would use *strangle*.

Comment: The second definition for "strangulate" is: *strangle; throttle.
sounding as though the speaker's throat is constricted.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA you are correct, the *second* definition for "strangulate" is indeed to strangle.  However, this is the *first* definition for "strangle," which doesn't have the medical term (all of its definitions are roughly the same and roughly applicable here) which is independently the more frequently used term ([by a factor of 50-100x](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strangle%2Cstrangulate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800)).

Comment: I've added the extra content of my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To strangle is to choke, "especially so as to cause death". So, either way, "strangling" or "strangulation", it's presumed lethal, just as "drowning" is. You can't be half-drowned; you either are or you aren't (well, you could be "nearly drowned".)

So anyway, if you don't die, you have only been "choked", not "strangled". That's why he said "Don't you **attempt** to strangle me!" Because, as she noted, if such an attempt were successful, he wouldn't be around to "sue" her.  But the state could charge her with manslaughter or murder "by strangulation".

Comment: What about "strangulate"? It's not clear whether it's a good/poor choice.

Answer (score 0):

Strangulate is generally used in a medical sense except by people that refuse to look up words. Those same people will say "conversate" instead of "converse"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).